# typing LINQ Queries in Controller max CPU usage 100%

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi I got this very strange problem I have a reports controller that is full of LINQ queries about 8k Lines of code I notice this when I was typing the codes in the 7k+ range. I check the resource monitor it shows 100% cpu usage in one of the cores.

I have Intel core i5 3rd gen, 16gb RAM, 7600rpm HDD,

Comment: You mean in visual studio? Simply too large file. Why not split it - partial classes help. And / or moving certain queries to separate objects (makes the class smaller).

Comment: Refactor your code, add more classes giving their [own responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: thanks I'll work into it. So the idea is to use a class for every group of query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having 8k lines of code in a constructor, or simply just in a file is bad design. A constructor should generally be initializing, not do heavy work. Put this in a method, and then a method should never be longer than it can fit entirely on a small screen (15-20 lines max). So you should definitely refactor your code. Especially watch out for long lines, as VS handles these badly - and by long lines I mean longer than 1k chars.
Even though screens today can show much, much more code than 20 lines, you will find that this approach makes your code much more readable.

Comment: Yes I thought so too. I need to study refactoring, you see I need to show the total amount of employees per shop the problem is the shops totaled to about 200+ so I need to query .Count() for every shop.

Comment: 1 point for You, That's right, and @StackOverlord please set as answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: You should maybe maintain a List of your shops? Then a sum of counts for each of them is a oneliner with linq